# Where to get Rhino Commons

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I'm working on an asp.net mvc project using nhibernate. At the moment I think Rhino Commons session management is the best spproach to control isession. But Where should I get Rhino Commons From? I found it located on Horn, Github, think the svn is obsolete.

Please point me to a version that works.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

On http://github.com/ayende/rhino-tools

but you can use this "Package management project" 
http://code.google.com/p/hornget/

It's very cool, you download it (it's not big), compile, execute and the application will get all files and compile for you, look the applications supported
http://code.google.com/p/hornget/wiki/SupportedPackages

Comment: Tried using horn, but read in the malinglist that rhino-tools would be obsolete from horn and moved to GIThub. Only thing is ayende moved rhino-mocks from the project, why??

Comment: Ayende is no longer the maintainer of Rhino Commons. Lorenzo Melato is.

Answer (score 5):

It's moved here...

http://github.com/lorenzomelato/rhino-commons

Answer (score 3):

http://github.com/ayende/rhino-tools

Moved: http://github.com/lorenzomelato/rhino-commons

Answer (score 0):

Since the Github one seems to have been removed by Ayende, the official one should be https://rhino-tools.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/rhino-tools/trunk/

Comment: That repository is **very old**

Comment: @mauricio, currently that seems to be the only official one, the one at http://github.com/lorenzomelato/rhino-commons, is nothing but just a mirror with no changes at all other updation of dependent libraries