# Pass in an XML document as a parameter to an Nhibernate ICriteria?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, nhibernate, sql-server-2008

So I have a query I need to run in NHibernate as a DetachedCriteria.  The problem I'm having (extremely similar to [this one](http://ayende.com/blog/2583/nhibernates-xml-in)) is that my query can have many thousands of input parameters, and there's a hard limit in SQL Server of 2100.  I believe that the solution is to put my parameter-list inside an XML document, and pass that as a single parameter.  It is described on the aforementioned page as working thusly:

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Customer))
    .Add(XmlIn.Create("id", potentiallyLargeAmount))
    List();
```

Which sounds EXACTLY like what I need.  However, I cannot find this XmlIn functionality anywhere in NHibernate!  Where is this functionality implemented?  How can I access it?  Also, how does it actually parse/handle the XML?  Do I need to conform to a schema of some sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is in Rhino-Commons.  I'm not all that familiar with it but after some googling I found it here: https://github.com/lorenzomelato/rhino-commons/blob/master/Rhino.Commons.NHibernate/NHibernate/XmlIn.cs

Here is where I found out where to get Rhino-Commons from:
[Where to get Rhino Commons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433820/where-to-get-rhino-commons)

Here is the link though:
http://github.com/lorenzomelato/rhino-commons